# MongoDB reading from slaves when synced

Tags: mongodb, replication

We're running a high load application on a MongoDB replica set and would benefit a lot from using the replicas to read the data for performance.  In our test setup we have the issue that not all secondaries are in sync with the primary which means that some documents are available on the primary but not on the secondaries.

Is there any approach how to manage that fact e.g. be telling the MongoDB setup to deliver the data from secondaries only if its available and to refer to the primary else?

Answer (score 1):

I am worried for the fact that you have a working replica set and don't understand the fundamentals of how replication in MongoDB works.

> be telling the MongoDB setup to deliver the data from secondaries only if its available and to refer to the primary else?

No, replication in MongoDB is not immediately consistent.

Reading from secondaries will provide stale data, sharding is recommended for what you wish to do.

Comment: I am familiar with the approach how replication works, the question was if there is some configuration option to tell the secondaries just to deliver data if it's guaranteed that it's already spreaded over all nodes. The point about sharding is obvious but the dataset is not that huge and it's more about read performance.

Comment: @ctp It is not due to how replication in MongoDB works. I mean for example what is "all secondaries", does that include hidden and delayed?

Comment: I agree with Sammaye. As alternative you can try to ensure replication on writes. It will slow writes but probably can help you to get consistent data on reading.

Comment: Indeed though do beware if you have 3 members and one goes down Mongo driver will wait forever for that last member to return.